# raster is split in multiple files when exporting to drive from Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I export a raster file to my drive, it gets split into 4 parts. Why is this happening?

It might be related to the `dimensions` attribute, which I don't use. But a default value is not given.

I used this command:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: exportImg, 
  description: 'description',
  region: roi, 
  scale: 10, 
  crs: 'EPSG:25832',
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

And the result is 4 rasters with name

> 'description-0000000000-0000000000',
>
> 'description-0000018944-0000000000',
>
> 'description-0000000000-0000018944',
>
> 'description-0000018944-0000018944'

Which obviously refers to the width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can find the detail about this situation via  (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting)
As they explained：

> *If the output image is large, it will be exported as multiple files. If you are exporting to GeoTIFF(s), the image is split into tiles. The filename of each tile will be in the form baseFilename-yMin-xMin where xMin and yMin are the coordinates of each tile within the overall bounding box of the exported image.*